# Can Mailgun Modify the Subject Line of an Outgoing Email?

Tags: mailgun

I'd like Mailgun to modify a text string in the subject line of outgoing emails with a specific subject line content.

What tools would we use to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Tom

Comment: Can you include an example of how you're sending (for example: via the mailgun API) and an example of how you want to modify the subject line?

Comment: If you are a developer, you can do that yourself. This detailed description may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150905/can-i-send-email-with-mailgun-sandbox-domain-under-my-local-os/68542876#68542876